# Ionic 2 tabs at the bottom for all pages in side menu

Tags: typescript, menu, tabs, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app with tabs and side menu. The problem is when I open any page of the side menu the tabs at the bottom disappear. Can someone provide me with solution how to keep tabs at the bottom all over the application, for all pages.

Comment: When you select from side menu you should push the tabs page with a specified selected tab index rather than pushing the page itself

Comment: @misha130 can you provide an example for your answer please

Comment: Same problem here! Any solution for this?

Comment: @djumerko did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Maverick09 I added extra tab which on click will open side menu with all pages I need and when the user clicks at one page of that side menu, that page is showed at that extra tab.

Comment: @djumerko : How do you open side menu on click of menu? Also how you  focus the extra tab when user opens the side menu from top hamburger menu directly. Is it possible to share sample code for this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Maverick09 https://github.com/janedzumerko/mladiAMS/tree/master/src Check this one. Check TabsPage and AktuelnoPage for example (it's one of the pages in the menu). I hope this will help you.

Comment: @djumerko: Indeed it is great help, exactly what I was looking for. thanks very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the conference app from github.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app